# Deploying Business processes with ANT

Tags: metadata, leads, migration-tool, ant, xml

I have tried to deploy business processes with ant. I seem to have the syntax wrong. I am seeing **Entity type: 'businessProcesses' is unknown**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Package xmls="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
  <types>
    <members>Lead.Process1 </members>
    <name>businessProcesses</name>
  </types>
  <version>32.0</version>
</Package>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are two ways:

**The entire object**

According to the [documentation](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_meta/Content/meta_businessprocess.htm) business processes are deployed as part of the [custom object metadata file (.object)](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_meta/Content/customobject.htm), so you get it if you include the object in the package xml

The package.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <types>
        <members>Lead</members>
        <name>CustomObject</name>
    </types>
    <version>33.0</version>
</Package>
```

**Just the BusinessProcess**

In the package.xml specify the BusinessProcess element:

```
<types>
    <members>Lead.Test Process</members>
    <name>BusinessProcess</name>
</types>
```

You can use the [Workbench tool](https://workbench.developerforce.com) to find out the value to put in the XML. In workbench, select Metadata Types & Components. Then select Business Processes. Then select the Object (e.g., Lead). Then find the fullName value.
[image: Lead Business Process in Workbench]

Snippet of the auto-generated object XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CustomObject xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
....
    <businessProcesses>
        <fullName>Test Process</fullName>
        <description>Lead Process for hardware division</description>
        <isActive>true</isActive>
        <values>
            <fullName>Closed - Converted</fullName>
            <default>false</default>
        </values>
        <values>
            <fullName>CustomLeadStep1</fullName>
            <default>false</default>
        </values>
        <values>
            <fullName>CustomLeadStep2</fullName>
            <default>false</default>
        </values>
        <values>
            <fullName>Open - Not Contacted</fullName>
            <default>false</default>
        </values>
        <values>
            <fullName>Working - Contacted</fullName>
            <default>true</default>
        </values>
    </businessProcesses>
....
</CustomObject>
```

Comment: I actually did try that but ant throws an error like Lead. HardwareLeadProcess was not found in the package.xml

Comment: OK. It should've worked with just the Object specified. I updated the answer to show how you can include just the Business process.

Answer (score 0):

Besides, you can use Visual Studio to obtain that info. First, you can retrieve the **BusinessProcesses** by using the following package:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>BusinessProcess</name>
    </types>     
    <version>53.0</version>
</Package>
```

After looking at the retrieved data, you will see something like that:

```
=== Retrieved Source
FULL NAME                      TYPE             PROJECT PATH                                                                                
─────────────────────────────  ───────────────  ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
Case.Case Default              BusinessProcess  force-app/main/default/objects/Case/businessProcesses/Case Default.businessProcess-meta.xml
```

Now you can see that there is a business process named as **"Case Default"** (or something else). Now you are sure you can use the following Package:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <types>
        <members>Case.Case Default</members>
        <name>BusinessProcess</name>
    </types>     
    <version>53.0</version>
</Package>
```