# Error in deploying Record types using ANT Tool

Tags: ant, migration-tool

I am able to retrieve the record type of opp object by first querying

```
SELECT sObjectType, DeveloperName FROM RecordType
```

But when i am deploying the same , i am getting the error `"Error in field : BusinessProcess - no business process named Opportunity- BISG Retail photo found <line 3 , column 18>"`

My package.xml to retieve and deploy the recordtype is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <types>
    <members>Opportunity.GMD_Record_Type</members>
    <members>Opportunity.BISG_Retail_Photo</members>
    <name>RecordType</name>
</types>
    <version>36.0</version>
</Package>
```

Any help/ideas?

Comment: Please refer [Deploying Business Process with ant](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/65954/deploying-business-processes-with-ant)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like in your file with the BISG_Retail_Photo RecordType you have `<businessProcess/>` defined named Opportunity- BISG Retail photo. But you might forgot to include this Business Process while deploying. You can check [Business Process Metadata docs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_businessprocess.htm) and ensure you have added this properly as well as add this Business Process to a package.xml file that you have posted.